# Should the monero community look to have the dev team working on the project full time?

Tags: development-roadmap, development-funding, core-development-team

Following the recent (Aug 2016) rise in the market cap,  the community is potentially big enough to have the developers paid (In XMR) to work on building out Monero full time.   Has this been discussed in the IRC chats/ dev meetings?     Is there a rough indication of how many hours a week fluffypony et al spend on the project and what it would cost for the community to sustain a couple of people full time (even if paid via project/goal funding) ?

Answer (score 13):

I'm reminded of this quote.

“It is difficult to get a man to understand something, when his salary depends on his not understanding it.” 
--Upton Sinclair

No, money creates a conflict of interest. Bounties that devs can choose to accept, as well as donations is fine, but once they get a salary their loyalty is no longer to the users, it is to the salary. What if there's a critical bug that could threaten the value of XMR? what if the salary he's being paid depends on him putting down his fellow devs to get to the top? What if the other devs get jealous/envious and try to make the paid devs lives difficult?

No, a salary is a horrible idea. They'll no longer be doing it because they enjoy working on an innovative, collaborative, vibrant technology, they'll be doing it because they look forward to the pay checque at the end of the month and they'll get fucking vicious if necessary to protect it.

Bounties, forum funding and donations are good, salaries, bad.

Comment: Good points, I guess more than a specified salary the thrust of the question is: the project/community/mkt cap are all now big enough that incentives could be provided (via bounties for example) to really increase the scope of the dev work being done.  It is now a much "bigger" project than a year ago when the mkt cap was $4m and the development work should be scaling up too.

Comment: It would be nice to see ore forum funding and bounties for users/by users that devs can petition to solve/finish. I think it's been rather quiet over there and is in need of attention. I have no idea how much funds the getmonero.org project has, but if they have money to spare then offering bounties which they partially fill and get the community to commit the rest wouldn't be a bad idea imo.